# c# code to prevent registering with textbox empty

Tags: c#

how do i prevent registering when some or all textboxes are empty?

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserRegistration UR = new UserRegistration();   //
    int x = UR.SaveDetails(
                txtFirstname.Text,
                txtLastname.Text,
                txtUsername.Text,
                txtPassword.Text,
                cboCourse.Text,
                cboLevel.Text,
                txtRegistrationAmount.Text,
                txtRegistrationId.Text,
                txtDateOfRegistration.Text);

    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());  

    if (txtFirstname.Text.Trim() = "")
        MessageBox.Show("YOU MUST ENTER ALL FIELDS!")
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to move the `if` to the top of your method?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to validate your TextBox. You can do this on every keystroke, at a later time, or on the Validating event.

The Validating event gets fired if your TextBox looses focus. When the user clicks on a other Control, for example. If your set e.Cancel = true the TextBox doesn't lose the focus. Hope this helps :)

Sample:

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "something")
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```